# Gorm & Postgres Connection reset by peer

Tags: postgresql, go, tcp, database-connection, go-gorm

**Context**

Currently I have a REST API that manages customer's data in a db. I'm using the following stack:

- Go 1.13
- github.com/jinzhu/gorm v1.9.1
- Postgres 11

I have the following connection settings.

```golang
// NewConnection ...
func NewConnection() (*gorm.DB, error) {
    config := getConfig()
        connStr := "host=xx.xx.xx port=5432 user=chavista-hatter dbname=my-db password=abc sslmode=verify-ca sslrootcert=/path/to/rcert sslcert=/path/to/cert sslkey=/path/to/key connect_timeout=0"
    db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", conn)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    db.DB().SetMaxOpenConns(25)
    db.DB().SetMaxIdleConns(25)
    db.DB().SetConnMaxLifetime(5 * time.Minute)

    db.SingularTable(true)

    if config.LogQueries {
        db = db.Debug()
    }

    return db, nil
}
```

I get a connection in the main class and inject that connection into a repository class that executes the queries through Gorm (ORM)

Main class

```golang
db, err := database.NewConnection()
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("failed to connect database --> %v", err))
    }
    fmt.Println("database connection established successfully")

defer db.Close()

customerRepo := customer.NewRepository(db)
```

Repository class

```golang
type repository struct {
    db *gorm.DB
}

//NewRepository 
func NewRepository(db *gorm.DB) Repository {
    return &repository{
        db: db,
    }
}

func (r *repository) Register(customer *models.Customer) (string, error) {

    err := r.db.Create(&customer).Error
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    return customer.key, nil
}
```

**Problem**

I sending over 500k request (INSERTS) to my db which have 512 connections available and after a few minutes the following error starts to come up repeatedly in postgres log:

```
unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction 
could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

For testcontainers add the following:

```golang
wait.ForListeningPort("5432/tcp")
```

Comment: This works, thx. So many examples just rely on `wait.ForLog` and that causes the problem

Answer (score 0):

How are you using `GetConnection` in your code?  It's creating a new connection pool every time it's called - ideally you'd only want to call it once, and pass that single connection around wherever it's used.

I would try changing it to this:

```
var db *gorm.DB
func NewConnection() (*gorm.DB, error) {
    if db != nil {
        return db, nil
    }
    config := getConfig()
    connStr := "host=xx.xx.xx port=5432 user=chavista-hatter dbname=my-db password=abc sslmode=verify-ca sslrootcert=/path/to/rcert sslcert=/path/to/cert sslkey=/path/to/key connect_timeout=0"
    var err error
    db, err = gorm.Open("postgres", conn)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    db.DB().SetMaxOpenConns(25)
    db.DB().SetMaxIdleConns(25)
    db.DB().SetConnMaxLifetime(5 * time.Minute)

    db.SingularTable(true)

    if config.LogQueries {
        db = db.Debug()
    }

    return db, nil
}
```

and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: I’m getting the connection once in my main class and then pass that connection to a repository class that executes the queries.

Comment: Please check my edit, I just described how I pass the connection to the repository class to be used.

Comment: interesting.  are you using transactions in your code at all?  Maybe there's a scenario where you  open one but then aren't ever committing / rolling back?